# How to install `workman` layout in Ubuntu?

Tags: keyboard-layout

I want to install [workman layout](https://github.com/deekayen/workman/tree/master/linux_console) on Ubuntu, I do not know how to do that?!

---

Workman layout blog: http://www.workmanlayout.com
Download: http://www.workmanlayout.com/blog/?page_id=964

Answer (score 3):

Click the next link to download it: [deekayen-workman-fb07f45.tar.gz](https://github.com/deekayen/workman/tarball/master). Extract `workman.iso15.kmap` or `workman-p.iso15.kmap` file from `/deekayen-workman-fb07f45/linux_console/` directory.

Then move it to the `/usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/` directory using [terminal](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UsingTheTerminal#Starting_a_Terminal):

```
sudo cp workman.iso15.kmap /usr/share/X11/xkb/symbols/workman
```

After, run:

```
setxkbmap -v workman && xset r 66
```

You should get something similar to this:

```
Warning! Multiple definitions of keyboard layout
         Using command line, ignoring X server
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   xfree86+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc(pc105)+workman+level3(ralt_switch)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
```

To switch back to QWERTY run:

```
setxkbmap us; xset -r 66
```

Comment: See `man setxkbmap` for more help.

Answer (score 2):

Obtain the layout from https://github.com/ojbucao/workman and
simply follow the instructions in `xmodmap/readme.txt` :

```
setxkbmap us; xmodmap xmodmap/xmodmap.workman && xset r 66
```

To switch back to QWERTY:

```
setxkbmap us; xset -r 66
```